# AOL search engine bot name?

Tags: search-engines, web-crawlers, name

Can somebody tell me the name of the AOL search engine bot?

I need to allow only this bot in robots.txt.

Answer (score 3):

AOL hasn't powered its own search engine for over a decade it now uses Google search.

> [***SOURCE***](http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2048976/Major-Search-Engines-and-Directories)
>
> In fact, in June of 1999 Netscape Search was updated and AOL/Netscape
>   search began to be powered by Google bringing their search volume to
>   approximately 3 million per day; huge for the time.

More related information can be found on AOL's website:

> [***SOURCE***](http://search.aol.co.uk/aol/about?v_t=na#webhome)
>
> Web search results are Websites listed in order of relevance, with
>   listings with the highest relevance appearing first. These listings
>   are administered, sorted and maintained by Google. These results may
>   contain objectionable material not endorsed by AOL. For information on
>   how Google sorts these listings, go to About Google.

Comment: Thanks @bybe means AOL is using Google spider and allowing Googlebot will allow AOL also?

Comment: Well AOL doesn't have a spider. It's Google, so yes.